# GitLab-runner fails to finish successfully due to "No such file or directory" error

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, artifact-deployer

I am using laravel-deployer package for deployment my project on my server.
I have the following `gitlab-ci` file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

image: lorisleiva/laravel-docker:7.4

.init_ssh: &init_ssh |
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  ssh-keyscan yourdomain.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

.change_file_permissions: &change_file_permissions |
  find . -type f -not -path "./vendor/*" -exec chmod 664 {} \;    
  find . -type d -not -path "./vendor/*" -exec chmod 775 {} \;

composer:
  stage: build

  script:
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress
    - cp .env.production .env
    - php artisan key:generate

  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 month
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env

  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-composer
    paths:
      - vendor/

npm:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-npm
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run production

  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 month
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - public/css/
      - public/js/

production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - *init_ssh
    - *change_file_permissions
    - cp .env.production .env
    - pwd
    - hostname
    - php artisan deploy yourdomain.com -s upload
    - cd /var/www/yourdomain.com/current
    - cp /var/www/yourdomain.com/current/.env.production /var/www/yourdomain.com/shared/.env
    - npm install
    - npm run production
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://yourdomain.com
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

It basically deploy laravel website, removes the previous version, copies the new one and changes its permissions so its readable by Nginx. All the steps are executed correctly but it always fails after it finishes with the following error:

```
✔
➤ Executing task artisan:migrate
✔
➤ Executing task deploy:symlink
✔
➤ Executing task deploy:unlock
✔
➤ Executing task cleanup
✔
➤ Executing task fpm:reload
✔
  Successfully deployed in 16.63s
$ cd /var/www/yourdomain.com/current
/bin/bash: line 127: cd: /var/www/yourdomain.com/current: No such file or directory
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Even though the pipeline works, its bugging me that I can't get a Passed report badge.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
npm install /var/www/yourdomain.com/current --verbose
npm run production --prefix /var/www/yourdomain.com/current
```

to avoid that error. And remove "cd" command.

Comment: Where is your package json file that you install? define that path "npm install PATH            --verbose"  "npm run production --prefix PATH"

Comment: got this after i define path on docker [error](https://ibb.co/gdq3kxz)

Comment: Why do you run "cd /var/www/yourdomain.com/current" command exactly?

Comment: I run this because - for copy my `.env` file , run my `php artisan tenancy:migrate` and `npm`

Comment: you do not need to run cd for copy command. Just cp is enough. And run npm as I mentioned above.